# Filter objects array with keys array [inverse]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I have this following keys array:

```
var keys = [{userId: "333"}, {userId: "334"}]
```

And this objects array:

```
var users = [
{id: "333", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "334", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "335", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "336", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""}
]
```

I need to change my `users Array` by filter it with my `keys Array`[inverse result].

Cant figure it out, get all the answers! (js, jquery, angular)

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `find()`.

```js
var users = [
{id: "333", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "334", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "335", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "336", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""}
]
var keys = [{userId: "333"}, {userId: "334"}]

var result = users.filter(function(o) {
  return !keys.find(function(e) {
    return e.userId == o.id
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array of `id`s and then you can just check for availability in this list

```js
var users = [
{id: "333", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "334", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "335", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""},
{id: "336", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: ""}
]

var keys = [{userId: "333"}, {userId: "334"}]

var idList = keys.map(function(x){ return x.userId});
var r = users.filter(function(x){
  return idList.indexOf(x.id) < 0
})

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Sorry but I need the inverse result.

Comment: @ZeevKatz So it should be all except mentioned list. Right? If yes, please see the update

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table for filtering.

```js
var keys = [{ userId: "333" }, { userId: "334" }],
    users = [{ id: "333", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: "" }, { id: "334", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: "" }, { id: "335", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: "" }, { id: "336", firstName: "", lastName: "", idCard: "", birthDate: "" }],
    filtered = users.filter(function (a) {
        return !this[a.id];
    }, keys.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.userId] = true;
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```